# WebRTC needing setup on pageload?

Tags: webrtc

I have a webRTC implementation working, but it requires a setup function to be run on page load.

```
setup = () => {
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers)
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = onicecandidate
  peerConnection.onconnectionstatechange = onconnectionstatechange(
    peerConnection,
  )
  peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = onnegotiationneeded
  peerConnection.ontrack = function({streams: [stream]}) {
    const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remote-video')
    if (remoteVideo) {
      remoteVideo.srcObject = stream
    }
  }
  mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, mediaStream))
}
```

Only then can I make the offer:

```
makeOffer = () => {
  peerConnection
    .createOffer()
    .then(offer => {
      return peerConnection
        .setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer))
        .then(() => offer)
    })
    .then(offer => {
      sendOffer(offer)
    })
}
```

If i attempt to run the setup just prior to the makeOffer function I get the error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on
> 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local offer sdp: The order of
> m-lines in subsequent offer doesn't match order from previous
> offer/answer.

My assumption is that it is due to the makeOffer running before something in the setup has completed, but nothing in the setup seems to be asynchronous. What do I need to do to be able to setup the connection and send the offer all at once?